# php echo codeigniter into javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have this bit of code in my codeigniter view:

```
<script>
    var content = [];
    content[<?php echo $storageItem["id"]; ?>] = "<?php echo form_open("/account/edititem", array("class" => "form-inline"), array("id" => $storageItem["id"], "item_loc" => "inventory", "acctid" => $acct_data->account_id)); ?>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <strong>Refine level:</strong>&nbsp;<input type="number" name="refine" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $storageItem["refine"]; ?>" <?php if ($storageItem["type"] != 4 && $storageItem["type"] != 5) { echo "readonly"; } ?> />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <strong>Broken?:</strong>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="attribute" class="form-control" value="1" <?php if ($storageItem["attribute"] == 1) { echo "checked"; } if ($storageItem["type"] != 4 && $storageItem["type"] != 5) { echo "disabled"; } ?> />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <strong>Bound?:</strong>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="bound" class="form-control" value="1" <?php if ($storageItem["bound"] == 1) { echo "checked"; } ?> />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <strong>Card 1:</strong>&nbsp;<input type="number" name="card0" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $storageItem["card0"]; ?>" <?php if ($storageItem["type"] != 4 && $storageItem["type"] != 5) { echo "readonly"; } ?> /></br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <strong>Card 2:</strong>&nbsp;<input type="number" name="card1" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $storageItem["card1"]; ?>" <?php if ($storageItem["type"] != 4 && $storageItem["type"] != 5) { echo "readonly"; } ?> /></br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <strong>Card 3:</strong>&nbsp;<input type="number" name="card2" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $storageItem["card2"]; ?>" <?php if ($storageItem["type"] != 4 && $storageItem["type"] != 5) { echo "readonly"; } ?> /></br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <strong>Card 4:</strong>&nbsp;<input type="number" name="card3" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $storageItem["card3"]; ?>" <?php if ($storageItem["type"] != 4 && $storageItem["type"] != 5) { echo "readonly"; } ?> /></br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        </div>";
</script>
```

I create array named 'content' in javascript and then need to stuff almost an entire form into it to be able to create a child row in DataTables.

( for more information regarding what I've been trying to do and where these variables come from, see [Datatables child row with PHP data from Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852110/datatables-child-row-with-php-data-from-codeigniter) )

I've tried escaping single and double quotes (PHP complains about this), `json_encode` (PHP also complains about this as I still need the quotes and PHP interprets the quotes as the end of the `json_encode`), I've tried surrounding the entire value of the javascript array with `'"'` and `"'"`, I've tried surrounding every line with `' '+` without success as well. How do I get this entire string into a form where javascript and PHP will parse it correctly and neither of them freak out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at what you're doing:

```
<script>
    var content = [];
    content[<?php [..snip..] ?>] = "<?php [..snip..] ?>
                                   ^---start of javascript string
            <div class="panel-body">  
                       ^---end of javascript string
                                  ^---start of another string
```

That means you have essentially:

```
variable = "some string stuff"variable-variable"more string stuff"
```

which is outright illegal JS.

The specific fix is to **ESCAPE** all of the strings in that html:

```
<script>
    yadayada
    <div class=\"panel-body\"> yada yadayada
               ^-----------^
```

But that doesn't fix the fact that this is incredibly bad code. You shouldn't be dumping loads of html into a JS string, and you should never be directly echoing text from PHP into a JS context.

If nothing else, why not generate all the content in PHP, then dump it all out as json?

```
<?php

$data = "blah blah blah blah";

?>

<script>
var content = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
```